# Ajustar una imagen en base a lo alto de una celda en HTML

Tags: html, css

Buenas tardes

¿Es posible hacer que una imagen que tengo dentro de una celda se ajuste al tamaño de esta última?

Deseo ponerle sombra lateral a una tabla que tengo en correo basado en HTML, pero este tipo de correo no permite la propiedad **box-shadow:** , es por eso que lo estoy sustituyendo por una imagen de sombra.

Me basé en la siguiente pregunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911656/is-it-possible-to-apply-css3-box-shadows-inline-to-html-e-mails

La sombra lateral ya la tengo posicionada y se visualiza, solo que no logro hacerla encajar al tamaño de la celda.

¿Alguna idea?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu código? pues podríamos responder con algo que no sirva, no sabemos cómo es la estructura.

Comment: Si puedes crear un "Fragmento de código" o un "JSfiddle" sería más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Podrías agregar la imagen como fondo,background-image o podrías usar la propiedad [Object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: perdón por contestar hasta ahora, han sido unas semanas un poco intensas de trabajo, pero el código html es este: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ys1tci4190pt7x5/ejemplo.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta estricta a tu pregunta es poner position:relative a la celda, y display:block, width:[el tamaño de la imagen en pixels], y height:100% a la imagen. Eso la estiraría como vos necesitás.

El tema es que Gmail elimina los position:relative de los mails, así que es mala idea usarlo en un template:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118072/gmail-removes-positionrelative-as-inline-css-email-temlate

La alternativa en este caso es usar la imagen como fondo de la celda. Gmail lo soporta, pero muchas versiones de Outlook no. De hecho, cualquier truco inteligente para resolver este problema va a chocar contra Outlook, pero podés revisar la lista de compatibilidades vos mismo:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

La realidad es que en general es mala idea hacer innovaciones estilísticas en un template de e-mail. El soporte de CSS y HTML es muy pobre, y además muy poco parejo entre distintos clientes. Mejor limitarse a lo básico.

Comment: muchas gracias Leandro! lo voy a probar

Comment: Desafortunadamente no he entrado mucho a detalle sobre el uso de CSS, aunque tengo nociones básicas, me gustaría saber si es buena idea hacer lo contrario a lo que pregunté en un inicio:  ¿es mejor definir el tamaño <alto y ancho> como fijos en mis celdas y que sean de las mismas dimensiones que mis imagenes? para no autoajustar nada y desde el principio ambas tengan las mismas dimensiones, ¿será lo optimo?